# Whitelisting URLs in Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I setup a dynamic link to invite users to download my app or be sent to my website (I own the domain but haven't built it yet format: www.my-domain.com) with Firebase Dynamic Links. Firebase recommends whitelisting URL patterns in the Firebase console, however I am unfamiliar with the RE2 syntax they require.

There are examples on Firebase and so I tried two:

1. ^https://my-domain.com/.*$
2. ^https://www.my-domain.com/.*\wshare?\wshareProfileName=\wBecky%20\wThomas$
   (where Becky Thomas is a users name & changes for each user)

I'm testing this on my iPhone and would expect this to work & be able to share the link however nothing happens and I receive the following error in the Xcode terminal:

"Error Domain=com.firebase.durabledeeplink Code=0 "We could not match param 'https://www.my-domain.com/share?shareProfileName=James%20Thomas' with whitelisted URL patterns in your Google project. [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429] [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429]"

Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you figure out how to this?

Answer (score 6):

The example didn't work for me either, I got it working by removing some of the slashes. This is the pattern I'm using...

```
^https://example.com.*$
```

If you want to match sub domains too you can use this...

```
^https://.*example.com.*$
```

Comment: This is the correct solution and the one that worked for me.

Comment: @Narcis did you fix it? How long does it take to work?  We added URL Whitelist like this but it still is not working? Do we have to update google info p list after updating it?

Comment: You can append ?d=1 to your dynamic link in a browser and it allows you to test the link and it will tell you if there's any errors with your setup

Comment: Issue is I am even unable to generate link on my App. This is the error that DynamicLinkComponent Shorten method gives
- some : Error Domain=com.firebase.durabledeeplink Code=0 "We could not match param 'https://pages.humanoo.com?id2=3711&type=internal&goTo=SelfServiceTeamDetails&id=23619' with whitelisted URL patterns in this Google project. [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429] [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429]" UserInfo={remoteStatus=INVALID_ARGUMENT, NSLocalizedFailureReason=We could not match param '

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression:

```
^https://www\.my-domain\.com/share\?shareProfileName=.+$
```

It's more restrictive because only accept the exact url with different values for shareProfileName.

Test the expressions on https://regex101.com/